# Linux randomly enables and disables tablet mode on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad, libinput, tablet-computer

I use a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 (Gen 6) laptop. Currently, I'm on Fedora.

In the GRUB menu, the internal keyboard works as expected. While using the OS, the keyboard is mainly unresponsive, but sometimes gets enabled and directly after that disabled. This is what it looks like observed with `libinput debug-events`:

```
-event16  SWITCH_TOGGLE           +13.842s  switch tablet-mode state 0
-event15  SWITCH_TOGGLE           +13.843s  switch tablet-mode state 0
-event16  SWITCH_TOGGLE           +13.892s  switch tablet-mode state 1
-event15  SWITCH_TOGGLE           +13.892s  switch tablet-mode state 1
```

`evtest` shows what device those events are attached to:

```
/dev/input/event15: ThinkPad Extra Buttons
/dev/input/event16: Intel HID switches
```

`libinput` is on version `1.24.0`.

This problem occurs (at least) with the following distros:

- OpenSUSE Tumbleweed
- Vanilla OS Orchid
- Arch
- Fedora

It would be best if I could make the tablet mode appear only when the laptop is "flipped", but completely disabling the tablet mode (or that the tablet mode disables the keyboard) is enough.

---

I tried to disable it with:

```
export LIBINPUT_IGNORE_DEVICE="17 20"
```

I also tried disabling both events at the same time with:

```
evtest --grab /dev/input/event15
evtest --grab /dev/input/event16
```

Although `libinput debug-events` stopped reporting the tablet mode switching, it still occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by blacklisting the Intel Integrated Sensor Hub.

1. Add the line `blacklist intel_ish_ipc` to the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.
2. Run `dracut -f` (on Fedora) or `update-initramfs -u` (Ubuntu).

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/fzyvvy/disable_intel_integrated_sensor_hub_ish/